# Spyder broke python script

Tags: python, spyder

I recently created a file using Spyder (in Anaconda). After an error which caused my pc to hang up and the subsequent restart, the file was corrupted/compiled? I am not even sure about it.

These are the first few line of the file if I open it in Spyder:

> ```
> ЈшIЩ‘x
> юбDЁ—
> ” lе*…QуОљрWµ®ћо…∞ЏIrаъ£ёQ∆j
> Cqбп÷°ЖG;—÷8чH,©И8•M'v`Kz]MвT.№5°шzлЭнbvю–ї7`z]р≠Ѓ"#Ы Me6Оj©
> АЈdРmCъ§ъ‘∆эCMсxat—√Ѓ»{§ШжќЙБ
> дYk*K dЦФЬ$„r4„тvЃ–'√гS
> Ѕ
> эtM„°гьЬ"¶≈пvДѓS
> k™єwjіб$шO}O)
> f
> ```

and here in the txt file

> ```
> \B7\F8I\99\D4x
> \FE\E1D\DD\D1
> \D3 l\E5*\C9Q\F3\8E\BD\F0W\B5\A8\CC\EEɰ\DAIr\E0\FA\A3\DEQ\C6j
> Cq\E1\EF֡\86G;\D1\D68\F7H,\A9\888\A5M'v`Kz]M\E2T.\DC5\A1\F8z\EB\9D
> \EDbv\FEл7`z]\F0\AD\AE"#\9B Me6\8Ej\A9
> ```

Can anyone help me fixing the file or understanding what happend? 
thanks in advance !

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry for this. We're working to provide autosave and recovery functionality for our next major version (Spyder 4) to help users in cases like this. Unfortunately, I don't know what happened in your case nor how to recover your file.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, that is nice to hear. I actually have my script back - I was able to recover a libreoffice file in which I checked my spelling. 
I also tried to decompile the file(assuming that it was compiled or something), but this did not work.

Comment: I am not sure this should be posted as an answer. You are aware Stack Overflow is not a forum, right? The box labelled "Your Answer" is for answers *only*.